# How to write table.column in MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I write `table.column` in PHP?

For example this is giving me error that there is no such a column in the table.

```
$aColumns = array( 'a.TIMESTAMP');
```

How to write that so it can actually work in php and mysql? When I put this code inside MySQL everything is acting normally. Any idea?

And when I put only one column to look into then

```
$aColumns = array( 'TIMESTAMP');
```

is working normally.

EDIT:

What I want to achieve is to get a certain `table.column`. Maybe my syntax is not correct.

When I put this code in the MySQL for example:

```
SELECT a.id,b.id from a,b
```

This is working perfectly when I do the same thing in PHP as I showed you before then I keep getting error

EDIT2:

```
    $aColumns = array( 'a.id','b.id','c.id');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "a,b,c" ;
    $swhere="a.id=b.id AND c.id=a.id"
```

This is a just example what I really need

Comment: I think you need to explain your question a bit better

Comment: I am just having a problem with the syntax

Comment: You're going to have to give a whole lot more information if you expect to get anything close to a meaningful answer.

Comment: We'd need to see your query code to give a sensible answer to this. Would you edit your question? I suspect the answer is that `mysql` result functions will only return array-based results containing column names, not table.column names. If you have clashing column names in multiple tables, you will need to alias those column names e.g. `SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit: +1 and see above ^

Comment: @halfer and then in the `where` part I would have like `a_id = b_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT
    a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

The trick here is *column aliasing*, which allows us to avoid a naming conflict in the resultset.

Comment: I'll edit my question and I'll put a php query in it so you can see what I really need. I mean this is correct answer but I would like use it in this enviroment.

Comment: I'm confused (and I should fix this in my question when I understand what you want): if `a.id` = `b.id` then you have no need to put both in the `SELECT` column list - just read one, and you know the other one will be the same. Would you explain? (I think we need to understand that before going on to tackle the update you've just made).